# Why are my images not uploading to Firebase storage using JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

Why is my page not uploading images to the firebase storage? i commented as much as possible to give a picture of what i was trying to achieve on the code below

```
    </style>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getStorage, ref } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-storage.js"
            const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "*",
        authDomain: "*",
        databaseURL: "*",
        projectId: "*",
        storageBucket: "*",
        messagingSenderId: "*",
        appId: "*",
        measurementId: "*"
        };

         // Initialize Firebase
         const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

            
        // Get a reference to the Firebase storage service
        var storage = firebase.storage();

        // Get the uploaded files data and store them in an array
        var files = null;
        document.getElementById("product-image").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        files = e.target.files;
        });

        // Sync the stored files to Firebase Cloud Storage
        document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("submit", function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            // Create a storage reference with a unique filename
            var fileName = Date.now() + '_' + files[i].name;
            var storageRef = storage.ref('images/' + fileName);
            
            // Upload the file to Firebase Cloud Storage
            var uploadTask = storageRef.put(files[i]);
            
            // Monitor the upload progress
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
            // Show the progress of the upload
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% complete');
            }, function(error) {
            // Handle unsuccessful upload
            console.error('Upload error:', error);
            }, function() {
            // Handle successful upload
            console.log('Upload successful!');
            
            // Get the download URL of the uploaded file
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                // Use the download URL to display the image or store it in the database
            });
            });
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: do any of the `console.log` occur? what does the HTML look like? what is `files.length` in the submit code? is there any network activity when you submit?

Comment: Your code here is importing two different versions of the Firebase SDK (v8.10.0 and v9.21.0), you should use only one - not both.

Comment: Please edit in the HTML form element and its contents into your question. On your form element, have you disabled the default action handler so that it doesn't refresh the page? You can also do this in your submit event listener using `addEventListener('submit', (event) => { event.preventDefault(); /* ... */ })`

Comment: the page refreshes after the submit. this is how the form looks like:                                         <form><div class="form-group"> <label for="product-image">Product Image:</label>
       <input type="file" id="product-image" name="product-image" accept="image/*" required>
                </div>
                </div> -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="send">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>